# panda: how to get unsuccessive rows by a list of index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get multiple rows from a pandas dataframe.

```
df.iloc[1]
```

could be used get one row, though, following code encounter an error.

```
df.iloc[1,3,8]
```

the error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df.iloc[1,3,8]
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in **getitem**(self, key)    1323             except (KeyError,
>   IndexError):    1324                 pass
>   -> 1325             return self._getitem_tuple(key)    1326         else:    1327             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)    1660     def _getitem_tuple(self,
>   tup):    1661 
>   -> 1662         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)    1663         try:    1664             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
>       186         for i, k in enumerate(key):
>       187             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
>   --> 188                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
>       189             if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
>       190                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have [%s] "
>
> IndexingError: Too many indexers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select multiple indices, you need to give `iloc` the indices as a list; try this:

```
df.iloc[[1,3,8]]
```

This effectively subsets the original DataFrame, but note that the operation is not in-place, so you'll have to assign the result to see the changes reflected in the original DataFrame:

```
df = df.iloc[[1,3,8]]
```